# Pagination failure

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to get around 200 records with 50 per page. So average of four pages. Now this is my first attempt at trying it in pdo. I know I am missing something, I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong or leaving out. So any help would be greatly appreciated. The code will pull from row 0 to row 50. But when I click on page numbers it wont go anywhere but the first 50 records. Also the variables I have moved around so many times, so look over the names of them lol.

```
//above this is just db connection and $condition variable

<table width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="6" align="left">
    <colgroup>
        <col span="3" style="background-color:black">
        <col style="background-color:black">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <th width="5%">No.</th>
        <th width="15%">Rank | Chain</th>
        <th width="25%">Username</th>
        <th width="15%">Last Sab</th>
        <th width="15%">AAT</th>
        <th width="20%">Sentry Rating</th>
    </tr>
    <?php

    if (isset($_GET['pagenum'])) {
        // $page = $_GET['page'];
        $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
    } else {
        //$page = 1;
        $pagenum=1;
    }
    $pagenum = (int)$pagenum;
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT `stats`.`name`, `stats`.`active`,  `stats`.`id`, `stats`.`strike`, `stats`.`defense`, `stats`.`sentry`, `stats`.`spy`, `stats`.`rank`, `stats`.`maxed`, `chains`.`name`, `chains`.`tag`, ((`stats`.`bpm`*1000000)+(`stats`.`ch`*450000)+(`stats`.`is`*1000000)+(`stats`.`ds`*200000)+(`stats`.`nun`*1000000)+(`stats`.`lt`*1000000)+(`stats`.`key`*600000)+(`stats`.`dog`*250000)) AS `tvalue` FROM `stats`, `chains` WHERE ".$condition." ORDER BY `tvalue` DESC LIMIT :start_from, :items_per_page");
    $query->bindParam(':start_from', $start_from);
    $query->bindParam(':items_per_page', $items_per_page);
    $start_from = 0;
    $items_per_page= 50;
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $start_from = ($pagenum -1) * $items_per_page;

    if ($query->rowCount() > $items_per_page) {
        $start_from = ($pagenum -1) * $items_per_page;
    }

    // Loop through results
   foreach($results as $data){

        // Display results in HTML table
        echo "<tr>";

        // Add/Remove your column names here
        echo "<td>". $num++ ."</td>";
        //echo "<td>". $data['rank'] ."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$data['rank']." |". $data['tag'] ."</td>";

        echo "<td>". $data['name'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>$pagenum</td>";//Last sab column
        echo "<td></td>";//AAT column
        echo "<td><em><font color='yellow'>". number_format($data['sentry']) ."</font></em></td>";

        // Close HTML table row
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    $query2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT `stats`.`name`, `stats`.`active`, `stats`.`id`, `stats`.`strike`, `stats`.`defense`, `stats`.`sentry`, `stats`.`spy`, `stats`.`rank`, `stats`.`maxed`, `chains`.`name`, `chains`.`tag`, ((`stats`.`bpm`*1000000)+(`stats`.`ch`*450000)+(`stats`.`is`*1000000)+(`stats`.`ds`*200000)+(`stats`.`nun`*1000000)+(`stats`.`lt`*1000000)+(`stats`.`key`*600000)+(`stats`.`dog`*250000)) AS `tvalue` FROM `stats`, `chains` WHERE ".$condition." ORDER BY `tvalue` ");
    $query2->execute();
    $total_records = $query2->rowCount();

    // Keep a record of total number of rows
    $total_rows = $total_records;

    // Using ceil function to divide the total records on per page
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $items_per_page);

    // Going to first page
    echo "<center><a href='stats.php?id=newwartab&pagenum=1'>First Page</a>  ";

    // Showing number of pages in between last page
    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++){
        echo "<a href='stats.php?id=newwartab&pagenum=". $i ."'>". $i ."</a> ";
    }

    // Going to last page
    echo "<a href='stats.php?id=newwartab&pagenum=". $total_pages ."'>Last  Page</a></center> ";

     // Calculate first and last item on current page
     $first = $pagenum * $items_per_page - $items_per_page;
     $last = $pagenum * $items_per_page;

     // Make sure the number can never be more than the total numer of rows
     if($last > $total_rows){
         $last = $total_rows;
     }
     // Showing the results
     echo "<br />";
     echo "<center>Showing ". $first ." to ". $last ." in total sab targets ". $total_rows ."</center>";
    ?>
</table>
```

A lot of commented out stuff. But hopefully whoever helps me can look over some of the bad coding and again I will appreciate any and all help that can be given cause I have worked too long just on this one code and want to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT ... DESC LIMIT $pagenum, $items_per_page");
```

Shouldn't be the page number, it should be the offset,

```
($pagenum -1) * $items_per_page
```

So on page `1` its `(1-1)*50` or `0` for the offset, for page `2` it's `(2-1)*50` or `50` etc.

Then with a limit of 50, you should get record `0-49`, `50-99` or something like that.

Unless page number isn't the page number, because if it is this is what you have for the first page.

```
 $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT ... DESC LIMIT 1, 50");
```

And for page 2

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT ... DESC LIMIT 2, 50");
```

Also You query should be here

```
//$pagenum = 1;
if (isset($_GET['pagenum'])) {
    // $page = $_GET['page'];
    $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
} else {
    //$page = 1;
    $pagenum=1;
}
//$page=1;

//<-- query should be after getting the page stuff from URL

$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And if you are going to concatinate them into your query you should at least cast them to int to prevent SQL Injection.

```
$pagenum = (int)$pagenum; //cast value to int.
```

And use **Prepared statements** for you queries to prevent SQLInjection.

Comment: OK i rearranged some stuff and moved the sql down below the $_GET['pagenum']. Im still getting same results as before. which is 0 to 50. on all 4 pages. ANd you was right with the 0 to 49 then 50 to 99 etc. cause thats what i want it to do but its not. so ill redit the above and add what i have now to see if it helps anymore. OK ABOVE IS NOW REDITTED

Comment: Also i want to state that i knew about the prepared statements i need done, i was gonna do it after i got it to work.

Comment: `$start_from = 0;`  is you offset, little surprise you get what you get.  try `$start_from = ($pagenum -1) * $items_per_page;`

Comment: ok i removed the $start_from = 0; an changed to $start_from = ($pagenum -1) * $items_per_page; and also if look above, i added bindparam to prevent injection and also the (int) to pagenum.. But everything seems to work now. and i appreciate the help cause ive been working on this for over 12 hours lol but anyways man thx...

Comment: Sure.  No problem, pretty simple for me, took me like what 10 minutes.